# putting a string value into a <p> tag from javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a program that is a three card brag game, which basically randomly selects a card using the random function to select a card from two arrays after that i've used a series of if statements decides what hand the player has.

i want to be able to get a piece of text from inside that if statement in javascript into a paragraph within the HTML.

This is an example of one of my if statements that decides one of the hands.

```
if(crand >= crand1 && crand >= crand2 || 
   crand1 >= crand && crand1 >= crand2 || 
   crand2 >= crand && crand2 >= crand1) {
         document.getElementById("P1").innerHTML='Player has high card';
}
```

this is what i have in my HTML body where i want that information to go

```
<p id='P1'></p>
```

Comment: A few things: Don't use a script tag on JSFiddle. Also, please don't use document.write. Finally, you can declare arrays as literals: `var array = [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: All i want is when the if that decide the different hands that that is sent to the <p id='p1'></p> but i really dont know how to do this. I've tried lots of different things and i dont know why it isnt working, because in my logic what i have should work but obviously im going wrong somewher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the code is in the document just before the `<body>` element closes (`</body`) so that the element can be found when your code executes.

```
<body>

  <p id="P1"></p>

  <script>

    // By placing your script after all the HTML elements, you 
    // ensure that they are loaded into memory by the time the
    // script runs.
    var p1 = document.getElementById("P1");

    var x = 10;

    if(x === 10){
      p1.textContent = "Hello!";
    }

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This answer is targeted to the title of the question and the OPs comment that it isn't working for him. The code posted in the Fiddle digresses wildly from this question. Of course, you are free to post an answer that addresses all those things.

Comment: It shows the OP how simple this task is and strongly implies that this isn't really the problem, much less the question that he should be asking.

Comment: All i want is when the if that decide the different hands that that is sent to the <p id='p1'></p> but i really dont know how to do this. I've tried lots of different things and i dont know why it isnt working, because in my logic what i have should work but obviously im going wrong somewhere

Comment: @AlexStephens So, I think your problem is not so much inserting text into the element, but understanding your logic and how to correctly write that. You may want to consider editing your question, explaining what your logic is and posting the relevant code here (as opposed to a link to a Fiddle).

Comment: I have rewritten my question, does that help ?

Comment: @AlexStephens A little. First, that condition is way to lengthy to understand. You should first consider grouping sections of it together with `(` and `)` to better understand and explain what separates the OR from the AND sections.  It would also be a good idea to log the values of `crand`, `crand1` and `crand1` just prior to that statement so you know what you have and you know what you are expecting. Clearly, your expression is never evaluating to true.

Comment: the if statements work because when i was using document.write() it was showing the right information. i just cant get the bit inside the if to display in my <p> tag

Comment: There are two reasons why this isn't working. 1) you have a coding error that is preventing the code from even processing. You can press F12 in your browser to open the developer tools and look at the `console` tab to see those. 2) Your `if` logic is never true. My money is on #2.

Comment: im getting the error of 'Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null'

Comment: This means that `document.getElementById("P1")` can't be found. This can happen for two reasons: 1) There is no element with an `id` of `P1` or (more likely) 2) you have this code executing before the `P1` element has been read into memory. Make sure your script is embedded into your HTML just before the `body` element closes (`</body>`) so that your code will be able to find any element it needs.

Comment: @AlexStephens I have updated my answer with your solution. Please up vote it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help